# I keep getting this error in my unity networked game but I don't know what it means

Tags: unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error in my unity networked game but I don't know what it means. Could someone please help me?

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.AddInterpolatedState (Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform+NetworkTransformState newState) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:612)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.CommitLocallyAndReplicate (Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform+NetworkTransformState networkState) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:370)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.<TryCommit>g__Send|41_0 (Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform+NetworkTransformState stateToSend) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:328)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.TryCommit (System.Boolean isDirty) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:345)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.TryCommitTransformToServer (UnityEngine.Transform transformToCommit, System.Double dirtyTime) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:311)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkTransform.OnNetworkSpawn () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Components/NetworkTransform.cs:705)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkObject.InvokeBehaviourNetworkSpawn () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Runtime/Core/NetworkObject.cs:799)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkSpawnManager.SpawnNetworkObjectLocallyCommon (Unity.Netcode.NetworkObject networkObject, System.UInt64 networkId, System.Boolean sceneObject, System.Boolean playerObject, System.Nullable`1[T] ownerClientId, System.Boolean destroyWithScene) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Runtime/Spawning/NetworkSpawnManager.cs:476)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkSpawnManager.SpawnNetworkObjectLocally (Unity.Netcode.NetworkObject networkObject, System.UInt64 networkId, System.Boolean sceneObject, System.Boolean playerObject, System.Nullable`1[T] ownerClientId, System.Boolean destroyWithScene) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Runtime/Spawning/NetworkSpawnManager.cs:389)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.HandleApproval (System.UInt64 ownerClientId, System.Boolean createPlayerObject, System.Nullable`1[T] playerPrefabHash, System.Boolean approved, System.Nullable`1[T] position, System.Nullable`1[T] rotation) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1563)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.StartHost () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0-pre.3/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:921)
NetHUD.StartButtons () (at Assets/AvatarGo/Scripts/Networking/NetHUD.cs:30)
NetHUD.OnGUI () (at Assets/AvatarGo/Scripts/Networking/NetHUD.cs:16)
```

I tried searching for answers on the internet before actually asking and they say that probably is because of a network script that I put on a not networked object. But I cheked and it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error occurs when you try to access an object that is null. In this case, it seems that the error is happening within the Unity Netcode package, specifically in the `NetworkTransform` component. This component is responsible for synchronizing the transform of game objects across the network.

To fix the error, you need to **identify the object that is null** and **make sure it is properly initialized** before accessing it. You may need to c**heck your code related to the `NetworkTransform` component** and **ensure that all required objects are properly initialized**.